# Want to load some jar files using java.library.path

Tags: java, jar

I want to load some jar files directly using java.library.path.
I don't want to use

```
System.load("/path/to/directory")
```

I can see the path using

```
java -XshowSettings:properties
```

and

```
 java.library.path = /usr/java/packages/lib/i386
    /lib
    /usr/lib
```

I want to add /usr/lib64 to this path

I tried

```
   echo " export LD_LIBRARY_PATH = $LD_LIBRARY_PATH:/usr/lib64/"
```

Actually, the path had the path to library /usr/lib64 but i guess it somehow got vanished as the server got restart so I want to fix the setting so that I don't need to change the variables again and again once the server gets started.

Comment: What do you want to load? Native libraries (searched in java.library.path) or Java classes from a Jar file (searched in the class path or boot class path)?

Comment: @SubOptimal I am using libpcap.so  and jpcap.jar files..I have written a utility that captures dns packets via  a particular port and performs some analysis on the packets.

Comment: Your library path contains a `...lib/i386` and you want to use `/usr/lib64`. I'm not sure if the 32bit JVM would be able to use a 64bit native library.

Comment: This is what that is disturbing me..It was on 64 previously and I used jpcap for 64 bit machine..I can see it is pointing to i386 now..

Comment: Have you reinstalled/updated your JDK/JRE? Are there more then one JDK/JRE installed on your computer?

Comment: just remove all existing java versions and re-installed java...The java lib path is still same..

Comment: And what have you installed? A 64bit JDK/JRE on a 64bit machine?

Comment: yes..that is a 64bit machine and I installed the jdk 1.8 for 64 bit machine

Comment: java lib path is pointing to 32 bit files..how can I change the path? when I copy the .so and jar files (they are of 64) so they don't work there ..

Answer (score 0):

Seems you system is somehow screwed.

On a 64bit machine and 64bit JRE 7 there are following results

```
file `which java`
[...]/bin/java: ELF 64-bit LSB executable, AMD x86-64, ...
```

.

```
java -XshowSettings:properties
# amongst others
/usr/java/packages/lib/amd64
/usr/lib64
/lib64
```

You could append the library path also as a JVM option

```
java -Djava.library.path=${your_path_goes_here}:${LD_LIBRARY_PATH} ...
```